# How can I ensure my GameSave Manager weekly backup actually happens?

Tags: windows

I configured a scheduled task for a weekly backup of all the saved games on my system to Dropbox, with 3 weeks of retention. However, the backup doesn't execute if my computer is in sleep, hibernate or powered down. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that this solution won't work for Windows XP.

1. Configure the task to run as a windows scheduled task in GSM.
2. Open the task scheduler and find your task. The task should be in the library and consist of of the prefix GSM, followed by a random string of letters and numbers.
3. Double click the task to open the task properties. You should have a window popup with 5 or 6 tabs depending on your Windows version. Select the "Settings" tab.
4. This tab should look like the below menu. The second option is what you need. Check it.

[image: Task Setting pane]
 *(image source: https://superuser.com/questions/312552/will-windows-scheduled-tasks-execute-if-the-computer-was-off-at-the-scheduled-ti)*

5. Press OK to close the task window, then close the task scheduler.

When the scheduled start time is missed, task scheduler will now attempt to run the task again as soon as possible.